# Fetch the data from firestore in the User Profile

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, fetch

I have a little problem. I make an app for a bookstore market. Right now, the book from each user is posting on Market Screen. In Profile Screen, the data is updated (name, profile image, about etc.). The problem comes when need to see the books from users, in their Profile Screen. On each Profile Screen, appears the same books posted by the current user.

MarketScreen code:

```js
export default function MarketScreen({navigation, route}) {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [deleted, setDeleted] = useState(false);
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  // const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  const fetchBook = async () => {
    try {
      const list = [];

      await firestore()
        .collection('user_book')
        .orderBy('postTime', 'desc')
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          // console.log('Total books from users', querySnapshot.size);
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const {
              userId,
              title,
              bookImg,
              postTime,
              author,
              genre,
              summary,
              price,
            } = doc.data();
            list.push({
              id: doc.id,
              userId,
              title,
              bookImg,
              postTime: postTime,
              author,
              genre,
              summary,
              price,
            });
          });
        });

      setBooks(list);
      if (loading) {
        setLoading(false);
      }

      console.log('Books', list);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const getUser = async () => {
    const currentUser = await firestore()
      .collection('user')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .get()
      .then(documentSnapshot => {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          console.log('User Data', documentSnapshot.data());
          setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());
        }
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchBook();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
    fetchBook();
    setDeleted(false);
  }, [deleted]);

  const deleteBook = bookId => {
    console.log(bookId);

    firestore()
      .collection('user_book')
      .doc(bookId)
      .get()
      .then(documentSnapshot => {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          const {bookImg} = documentSnapshot.data();

          if (bookImg !== null) {
            const sotageRef = storage().refFromURL(bookImg);
            const imageRef = storage().ref(sotageRef.fullPath);

            imageRef
              .delete()
              .then(() => {
                console.log('${bookImg} has been deleted');
                deleteFirestoreData(bookId);
                setDeleted(true);
              })
              .catch(e => {
                console.log('Error while deleting the image', e);
              });
          } else {
            deleteFirestoreData(bookId);
          }
        }
      });
  };

  const handleDelete = bookId => {
    Alert.alert('Delete Book', 'Are you sure?', [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      {text: 'Confirm', onPress: () => deleteBook(bookId)},
    ]);
  };

  const deleteFirestoreData = bookId => {
    firestore()
      .collection('user_book')
      .doc(bookId)
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        Alert.alert('Your book was deleted from MarketStore');
      })
      .catch(e => console.log('Error deleting book', e));
  };

  const ItemSeparatorView = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{height: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'black'}}></View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={books}
        extraData={query}
        ItemSeparatorVie={ItemSeparatorView}
        keyExtractor={(index, item) => item.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.bookFeed}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('UserBook', {item})}>
            <View style={styles.textViewStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.txt1}>
                Posted by:
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() =>
                    navigation.navigate('Profile', {userId: item.userId})
                  }>
                  <Text style={styles.txtUser}>{item.userId}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.txt1}>
                Title:
                <Text style={styles.txt2}>{item.title}</Text>
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.txt1}>
                Author:<Text style={styles.txt2}>{item.author}</Text>
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.txt1}>
                Genre:<Text style={styles.txt2}>{item.genre}</Text>
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.txt1}>
                Price:<Text>{item.price} lei</Text>
              </Text>
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Text>{moment(item.postTime.toDate()).fromNow()}</Text>
                {user.uid === item.userId ? (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => handleDelete(item.id)}
                    style={{marginLeft: '20%'}}>
                    <Icon
                      name="trash"
                      color={'#DC143C'}
                      size={30}
                      style={{marginTop: -10}}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                ) : null}
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.book}>
              {item.bookImg !== null ? (
                <Image
                  style={styles.bookImage}
                  source={{
                    uri: item.bookImg,
                  }}></Image>
              ) : (
                <Text>SFSAFAS</Text>
              )}
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}></FlatList>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

ProfileScreen code:

```js
const onLogout = () => {
  firebase.auth().signOut();
};

export default function ProfileScreen({navigation, route}) {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const [deleted, setDeleted] = useState(false);
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  const userIdd = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  const fetchBook = async () => {
    try {
      const list = [];

      await firestore()
        .collection('user_book')
        .where('userId', '==', route.params ? route.params.userId : user.uid)
        .orderBy('postTime', 'desc')
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          // console.log('Total books from users', querySnapshot.size);
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const {
              userId,
              title,
              bookImg,
              postTime,
              author,
              genre,
              summary,
              price,
            } = doc.data();
            list.push({
              id: doc.id,
              userId,
              title,
              bookImg,
              postTime: postTime,
              author,
              genre,
              summary,
              price,
            });
          });
        });

      setBooks(list);
      if (loading) {
        setLoading(false);
      }

      console.log('Books', list);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const getUser = async () => {
    await firestore()
      .collection('user')
      .doc(route.params ? route.params.userId : user.uid)
      .get()
      .then(documentSnapshot => {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          console.log('User Data', documentSnapshot.data());
          setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());
        }
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
    fetchBook();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchBook();
    setDeleted(false);
  }, [deleted]);

  const deleteBook = bookId => {
    console.log(bookId);

    firestore()
      .collection('user_book')
      .doc(bookId)
      .get()
      .then(documentSnapshot => {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          const {bookImg} = documentSnapshot.data();

          if (bookImg !== null) {
            const sotageRef = storage().refFromURL(bookImg);
            const imageRef = storage().ref(sotageRef.fullPath);

            imageRef
              .delete()
              .then(() => {
                console.log('${bookImg} has been deleted');
                deleteFirestoreData(bookId);
                setDeleted(true);
              })
              .catch(e => {
                console.log('Error while deleting the image', e);
              });
          } else {
            deleteFirestoreData(bookId);
          }
        }
      });
  };

  const handleDelete = bookId => {
    Alert.alert('Delete Book', 'Are you sure?', [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      {text: 'Confirm', onPress: () => deleteBook(bookId)},
    ]);
  };

  const deleteFirestoreData = bookId => {
    firestore()
      .collection('user_book')
      .doc(bookId)
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        Alert.alert('Your book was deleted from MarketStore');
      })
      .catch(e => console.log('Error deleting book', e));
  };

  const ItemSeparatorView = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{height: 2, width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'black'}}></View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.container}
        contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <Image
          style={styles.userImg}
          source={{
            uri: userData
              ? userData.userImg
              : 'https://static.remove.bg/remove-bg-web/2a274ebbb5879d870a69caae33d94388a88e0e35/assets/start-0e837dcc57769db2306d8d659f53555feb500b3c5d456879b9c843d1872e7baa.jpg',
          }}></Image>

        <Text style={styles.userName}>{userData ? userData.name : 'Test'}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.userName}>
          {/* {route.params ? route.params.userId : userIdd} */}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.aboutUser}>
          {userData ? userData.about || 'No details added' : ''}
        </Text>

        <View style={styles.userBtnWrapper}>
          {route.params ? (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.userBtn} onPress={() => {}}>
                <Text style={styles.userBtnTxt}>Message</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.userBtn}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Messages')}>
                <Text style={styles.userBtnTxt}>My messages</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.userBtn}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate('EditProfile');
                }}>
                <Text style={styles.userBtnTxt}>Edit</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.userBtn}
                onPress={() => onLogout()}>
                <Text style={styles.userBtnTxt}>Logout</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </>
          )}
        </View>

        <View style={styles.userInfoWrapper}>
          <View style={styles.userInfoItem}>
            <Text style={styles.userInfoTitle}></Text>
            <Text style={styles.userInfoSubTitle}>{books.length}Books</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        {books.map(item => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.bookFeed}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('UserBook', {item})}>
            <View style={styles.textViewStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.txt1}>
                Title:
                <Text style={styles.txt2}>{item.title}</Text>
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.txt1}>
                Author:<Text style={styles.txt2}>{item.author}</Text>
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.txt1}>
                Genre:<Text style={styles.txt2}>{item.genre}</Text>
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.txt1}>
                Price:
                <Text style={{color: 'black', fontStyle: 'normal'}}>
                  {item.price} lei
                </Text>
              </Text>
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Text>{moment(item.postTime.toDate()).fromNow()}</Text>
                {user.uid === item.userId ? (
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleDelete(item.id)}>
                    <Icon
                      name="trash"
                      color={'#DC143C'}
                      size={30}
                      style={{marginLeft: '20%'}}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                ) : null}
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.book}>
              {item.bookImg !== null ? (
                <Image
                  style={styles.bookImage}
                  source={{
                    uri: item.bookImg,
                  }}></Image>
              ) : (
                <Text>SFSAFAS</Text>
              )}
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately your problem comes down to two things: How you manage the current user and it's linked variables and how you manage the ID of the user who's profile you are viewing. I'll cover the fundamentals of each issue, but it'll be up to you to fully adapt them to your code.

### Signed-in User State

When your page is first loaded, `firebase.auth().currentUser` is in [an intermediate state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) and will return `null`. In addition, if a user were to logout, your component will not update to reflect that causing your resource listeners to throw errors depending on your security rules. To correctly listen for the current user, you should use an effect hook with `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()`. This listener reports when a user logs in, when they log out, when their session is validated and when the user is switched.

This can be done using these hooks:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);
// type of user: firebase.User | null | undefined
//   - `undefined` means the user state is still being checked (e.g. show a loading icon)
//   - `null` means not signed in
//   - `firebase.User` means a user is signed in and has been validated

// NOTE: onAuthStateChanged conveniently returns it's own cleanup function
// NOTE: Make sure to pass in `[]`, otherwise `user` will get updated in an infinite loop
useEffect(() => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser), []);
```

You can also listen for errors:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);
// type of user: firebase.User | null | undefined
//   - `undefined` means the user state is still being checked (e.g. show a loading icon)
//   - `null` means not signed in
//   - `firebase.User` means a user is signed in and has been validated

useEffect(() => {
  return firebase.auth() // return listener's cleanup function
    .onAuthStateChanged({
      next: setUser,
      error(err) {
        // something unexpected went wrong with Firebase Auth
        console.error('onAuthStateChanged Error:', err);
        setUser(null); // treat as signed out for safety
      }
    });
}, []); // make sure to use `[]` here, otherwise `user` will be updated in an infinite loop
```

### Obtaining the user ID to be viewed

Now that you can guarantee that `user` works correctly, you can get the user ID of the profile to be viewed. Based on your existing code, this can either be given as a parameter or uses the current user ID. However, we need to be able to handle the following situations:

| ID param | User | type: `viewedProfileId` | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| provided | signed in | string | access given profile's data |
| provided | signed out | string | access given profile's data (if public) OR navigate to login page (if auth required) |
| provided | *initializing* | string | access given profile's data (if public) OR show loading icon (if auth required) |
| omitted | signed in | string | access own user's profile data |
| omitted | signed out | `null` | navigate to login page |
| omitted | *initializing* | `undefined` | show loading icon |

To create `viewedProfileId` as in the above table, you would use:

```js
const { userId: userIdParam } = route.params || {};
// type of userIdParam: string | undefined

const currentUserId = user ? user.uid : undefined;
// type of currentUserId: string | undefined
// for convenience over using `user && user.uid` repeatedly

const viewedProfileId = userIdParam || currentUserId || user;
// intended type of viewedProfileId: string | null | undefined
// the value of `viewedProfileId` will be:
//   `userIdParam` (if truthy), OR
//   the current user's ID (if signed in and valid), OR
//   `null` (when user is signed out), OR
//   `undefined` (when authentication is still initializing)

// TODO: Make use of viewedProfileId in hooks/render
```

**Note:** While the above snippet could be adapted to make use of `useState` and `useEffect`, it's not directly making use of any asynchronous functions, which means that using state in that way would just cause unnecessary re-renders of your component.

### Scaffold

Bringing the above pieces together, produces the following starting point. As I stated earlier, it's beyond the scope of StackOverflow for total refactoring of your code. The comments are included for informational purposes, most can be removed once you see what's going on. This code also makes the assumption that a user must be logged in before they are able to grab profile information.

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);
// type of user: firebase.User (signed in) | null (signed out) | undefined (initializing)

// Attach listener for user state changes
useEffect(() => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser), []); 

const { userId: userIdParam } = route.params || {};
// type of userIdParam: string (view profile of given ID) | undefined

const currentUserId = user ? user.uid : undefined;
// type of currentUserId: string (when signed in) | undefined (when signed out/initializing)
// for convenience over using `user && user.uid` repeatedly

const viewedProfileId = userIdParam || currentUserId || user;
// intended type of viewedProfileId: string | null | undefined
// the value of `viewedProfileId` will be:
//   the `userId` route parameter (if truthy - view profile of this ID), OR
//   the current user's ID (if signed in and valid - view own profile), OR
//   `null` (when user is signed out - error state), OR
//   `undefined` (when authentication is still initializing - still loading)

const [viewedProfileData, setViewedProfileData] = useState(undefined);
// NOTE: named `viewedProfileData` because conventionally `userData` should be reserved for the current user's data (not potentially another user)
// type of viewedProfileData: ProfileDataModel | null | undefined
//   - `undefined` means `viewedProfileId` hasn't been set yet and/or data
//      hasn't been loaded yet (e.g. show a "loading profile" loading icon)
//   - `null` means the profile data doesn't exist
//   - `ProfileDataModel` means a profile has been loaded successfully

const [viewedProfileBookList, setViewedProfileBookList] = useState(undefined);
// NOTE: named `viewedProfileBookList` because `books` should be `bookList` (prevent typos against `book`) and then named to match `viewedProfileData`
// type of viewedProfileData: BookModel[] | undefined
//   - `undefined` means `viewedProfileId` hasn't been set yet and/or data
//      hasn't been loaded yet (e.g. show a "searching for books" loading icon)
//   - `BookModel[]` means a profile's book list has been loaded successfully (may be empty)

// Fetch profile data, after suitable user state
useEffect(() => {
  // While loading user state, don't fetch any data
  if (typeof user === "undefined") {
    return; 
  }

  // When not logged in, navigate away to login screen
  if (user === null) {
    navigation.navigate('Login');
    return;
  }

  // If here, user is logged in and viewedProfileId will be a user ID to grab (that may not exist!)

  fetchProfile(viewedProfileId);  // updates viewedProfileData
  fetchBookList(viewedProfileId); // updates viewedProfileBookList

  return () => {
    setViewedProfileData(undefined);
    setViewedProfileBookList(undefined);
  }
}, [viewedProfileId, user]);

// convert the state variables for use in the render
const loading = typeof viewedProfileData === "undefined";
const loadingBookList = typeof viewedProfileBookList === "undefined";
const isOwnProfile = viewedProfileId === currentUserId;

// e.g. use `currentUserId === item.userId` instead of `user.uid === item.userId`
// e.g. use `isOwnProfile` instead of `route.params`

return (/* the render */);
```

**Note:** In the above code I use three-value logic: `undefined` (initializing), `null` (invalid/not found) and "other" (the value). It's up to you if you want to do the same or if you want to use the two-variable approach: `someVariable` (the value, with some default value) and `someVariableLoaded` (boolean, stating whether `someVariable` is valid or not). Using the latter would suit array structures like the list of books.