# Getting user data by currentUser id from Firestore returns null

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database of users with data like id and displayName. I have two types of users in my db: one with identity of "parent" and the other "author". I want to change the content of main page and navigation bar depending of which identity the currentUser has.

I retrieve currentUser data without any problem but when I try to find the same user in db by currentUser id i recieve `null`. This only happens when i tried to make one global function instead of pasting to every component.

My UserContext.js looks like that

```
export const UserContext = createContext({
    currentUser: null,
    setCurrentUser: () => null,
});

export const UserProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);


    useEffect(() => {

        const unsub = onAuthStateChangedListener((user) => {
            // console.log(user);
            if (user) {
                createUserDocumentFromAuth(user);
            }
            setCurrentUser(user);

        });

        return unsub;
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!currentUser) return;
        const docUserRef = doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid);

        const getData = async () => {
            const docSnapshot = await getDoc(docUserRef);
            setUser(docSnapshot.data());
            console.log("snapshot: ", docSnapshot.data())
        }
        getData();
    }, [])

    const value = {currentUser, setCurrentUser, user, setUser};

    return <UserContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
}
```

And here's where I am using it

Navbar.js

```
 const {currentUser, user} = useContext(UserContext);

    const navigate = useNavigate();



    console.log("user: ", user)
    console.log("user current: ", currentUser)



    if (currentUser && user.identity === "parent") {
        return (
            <Nav>
                <NavItem>{currentUser.displayName}</NavItem>
                <NavItem>Parent</NavItem>
            </Nav>)
    } else if (currentUser && user.identity === "author") {
        return (
            <Nav>
                <NavItem>{currentUser.displayName}</NavItem>
                <NavItem>Author</NavItem>
            </Nav>)
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? can you try to add catch block and update the post with an error?

Comment: I do not get any errors, only when I'm console logging the user i get ```null```

Comment: When your page is first loaded, `firebase.auth().currentUser` is in an intermediate state and will return null. Have a look at this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137890/fetch-the-data-from-firestore-in-the-user-profile/67140848#67140848) once.

Comment: Also check this [Article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0) which might be helpful for you.